# Calling a variable from outside of a function

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm so stumped. I'm hoping someone can help me out here! I'm trying to call the variable named "time" from outside of a function.

**Here is my code:**

```
var myXML:XML = new XML();
var XML_URL:String = "time.xml";
var myXMLURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(XML_URL);
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(myXMLURL);
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);

var time;
function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void
{
  time = XML(myLoader.data);
}

trace(time);
```

**Here is what my XML looks like**

```
<time>10</time>
```

Every time I run the trace(time); outside of the function - I get an "undefined" message in the output window.

How can I access the variable "time" from outside of my function so I can assign it to another variable like this:

*`var VIDEOS_SECONDS = time;`*

Thank you so much for any help!

Timothy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AS3 access variable outside of function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271403/as3-access-variable-outside-of-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of it looks correct, the issue is the xml file is loading asynchronously and you expect it to load synchronously.

If you move `trace(time)` right after `time = XML(myLoader.data);` you should see the expected value. You can call another function from that `COMPLETE` handler to setup the rest of your code that relies on data being loaded first:

```
var myXML:XML = new XML();
var XML_URL:String = "time.xml";
var myXMLURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(XML_URL);
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(myXMLURL);
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);

var time;
function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void
{
  time = XML(myLoader.data);
  trace(time,new Date());
  //time is ready here
}
//although time is global, xml hasn't loaded at this point yet, check timestamps
trace(time,new Date());
```

Comment: George. Thanks for the quick reply. I kinda understand what you're saying and I've done this almost but how would I get that "time" into VIDEOS_SECONDS_GAP = time - because right now VIDEOS_SECONDS_GAP is equal to "3" but I want the xml value placed into that instead so I can change it from just the xml file. Hope this makes sense!

Comment: OK! I added another function! How would I go about this... - http://i.stack.imgur.com/K08GM.jpg

Comment: Could you post a separate question with the code snippet as text ?

Comment: Sure thing! I really appreciate it - http://pastie.org/10904236 - I'm just trying to place the variable "test" into the variable VIDEOS_SECONDS_GAP.

Comment: How about posting a separate question ? Also, let's say you copy the value into the ```VIDEOS_SECONDS_GAP``` variable ? mention in the question when/how you plan to use this value.

Comment: Like completely post a new post/question? Wouldn't that be a duplicate post/question?

Comment: When do you plan to use this VIDEOS_SECONDS_GAP in the finalised code ?

Comment: Outside and after of my xmlLoaded.

Comment: in xmlLoaded tim will have a value set from XML. Set ```VIDEOS_SECONDS_GAP ``` to be equal to that value. Later on when you go from one video to another the variable should have the correct value (but straight after starting the xml load but before it completes). Makes sense ?